# ORACLE SQL - (SYSDATE-1) ignoring weekend

Tags: sql, datetime, oracle11g

I am relatively new to SQL and need to construct a small productivity query to retrieve results from the day prior (in this case, time of the first and last picking transaction, and then a count of total picks).

The issue is that obviously on Monday when this query runs, it returns no results and as such we never get the friday results. I would therefore like to know how to ignore the weekend days.

This is my query as of now:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, MIN(END_TRAN_TIME), MAX(END_TRAN_TIME), COUNT(TRAN_TYPE)
FROM T_TRAN_LOG
WHERE WH_ID ='W376' AND  TRUNC(END_TRAN_DATE) = TRUNC(sysdate-1) AND TRAN_TYPE IN ('301', '303', '305')
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the weekend days, you can modify the query to check if the day of the week is not a weekend day (Saturday or Sunday).

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, MIN(END_TRAN_TIME), MAX(END_TRAN_TIME), COUNT(TRAN_TYPE)
FROM T_TRAN_LOG
WHERE WH_ID ='W376' AND
TRUNC(END_TRAN_DATE) = TRUNC(sysdate-1) AND
TRAN_TYPE IN ('301', '303', '305') AND
TO_CHAR(END_TRAN_DATE, 'DAY') NOT IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Hope this helps